# remove all <a href> from a specific div

Tags: jquery, html

I would like to remove all `<a href>` from a specific div.

```
<div class="postInfo">
    <a href>
</div>
```

I am trying

```
$('.postInfo href').remove();
```

that's not working. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `href` is not an element.  You need to learn basic selectors.

Comment: The selector is the tag name which boils down to the first word after the opening `<` and the first word after the `</` in the tag close. So, for the `<a href="...">...</a>` it would be "a" just as it is "p" for `<p>...</p>`. (This is something about HTML you should know to be fooling with javascript or jquery.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

target the anchor, not the href :

```
$('.postInfo a').remove();
```

Comment: Enjoy the free rep `:P`

Comment: @Bojangles - I'm all "rep'ed" up, so it doesn't matter as I'm not getting it anyway!

Comment: Do you not get rep beyond a certain amount? At least that's what you're implying

Comment: @Bojangles 200 rep max per upvote per day, after that you only get rep for accepted answer.

Comment: Yup, 200 max per day, after that it doesn't stick and you're only answering out of the goodness of your heart.